# Select cells with rowspan using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have auto-generate html table, some cells of this table have rowspan property. How select this cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this will work:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('table td[rowspan="*"]').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Or this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("table td").each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("rowspan"))
      $(this).css('background-color', 'red')
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "[rowspan]" )
```

will give you all the tags with rowspan attribute

Comment: Use ie8, this expression chose all cells

Comment: What is the version of jQuery you are using?

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcLo61se/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table').find('td[rowspan]').css('background-color', 'red');

    // or
    // $('table').find('td[rowspan=2]').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Comment: The first variant - all table have red background, use ie8. The second varient - I have different value of rowspan 2, 3, ....